# Can we convert infinite sums into infinite products?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, infinite-product

Is there any method to convert an infinite sum (of any type) into an infinite product? That is, a method such that  the equality 
 $  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_n = \prod_{n = 0}^{\infty} f(a_n)$

holds.

Comment: Hint: check $e^x$.

Comment: You can check Weierstrass factorization theorem for entire functions in order to get a generalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to a more general question. Given a sequence of numbers
$\,c_1,c_2,\dots,\,$ define
$$p_0:=1,\;\; p_1:=p_0+c_1p_0=(1+c_1)p_0,\;\; p_2:=p_1+c_2p_1=(1+c_2)p_1,\dots\;.$$ Now assuming the limit exists,
$$\lim_{n->\infty}p_n=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+c_n)=1+c_1p_0+c_2p_1+\dots=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n,\;b_n:=c_n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k.$$

Now, to reverse the process, given a sequence of numbers
$\,a_0, a_1, \dots\,$ and assume that $a_0\ne 0.$ Using the
previous method of defining $\,p_0,p_1,\dots\,$ define
$$c_1:=\frac{a_1}{a_0 p_0},\;c_2:=\frac{a_2}{a_0 p_1}, \;\dots,\; c_n:=\frac{a_n}{a_0 p_{n-1}},\quad\dots\quad\textrm{and}\quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = a_0\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+ c_n).$$
Finally, letting $q_0:=a_0,\; q_n:=1+c_n$ for $n>0,\;$ then $\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \prod_{n=0}^\infty q_n.$

The advantage of this method is that it works for finite sums and products also. It is very similar to [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) to convert sums to continued fractions.

An example of the method converts the geometric series
into an infinite product
$$ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +\dots = \Big(1+\frac{x^1}{1}\Big)
\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{1+x}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{x^3}{1+x+x^2}\Big)\cdots.
$$

Comment: It's not very clear what you are talking about (I think you made it too general). Could you elucidate with an example?