# Proof of a series having infinitely many zeros in the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read an interesting question recently. This is about a series having infinitely many zeros inside the unit disc $U$. The series is 
\begin{equation*}
   f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 5^k z^{n_k},
\end{equation*} where $\{n_k\}$ is a sequence of integers such that $n_1 \ge 2$ and $n_{k+1}>2kn_k$. I have shown that $f \in H(U)$ and it does not have radial limit at any point of the unit circle $\partial U$. However, I can't show that it has infinitely many zeros inside $U$. The tools that I can apply are graduate level complex analysis such as Rouche's theorem, the open mapping theorem, the maximum modulus theorem, Schwarz lemma, Runge's theorem, the Mittag-Leffler theorem and etc. Anyone can help?

Comment: Maybe you can turn it into an infinite product and see the zeros directly. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2477308/289217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function has the property that on the circle $|z|=1-\frac{1}{n_k}, k \ge 10$, $|h(z)|>C5^k$, where we can take for example $C=\frac{1}{100}$

(note that $(1-\frac{1}{n_k})^{n_k} \ge \frac{1}{3}$ as that sequence converges increasingly to $\frac{1}{e}$ with the inequality already happening for $k \ge 10$ and $n_k>k$, while for $m>k,(1-\frac{1}{n_k})^{n_m} \le (\frac{1}{e})^{2^{m-k}(m-1)...k} < 6^{-m}$ so the corresponding terms form a geometric sum that converges to a small finite number, while the smaller terms sum in absolute value to obviously less than $\frac{1}{4}5^{k}$ by the trivial estimate and the corresponding geometric series)

Assume now that $h$ has finitely many zeroes only (could be none here of course). Let $B$ a finite Blaschke product with the same zeroes (including multiplicities etc, where we take $B=1$ if $h$ has no zeroes). Then $g=\frac{h}{B}$ has no zeroes in the unit disc and is analytic and still satisfying $|g(z)| > C5^k, |z|=1-\frac{1}{n_k}$, since $|B(z)| <1, |z| <1$.

But then $\frac{1}{g}$ is analytic in the unit disc and by maximum modulus, $|\frac{1}{g}| < \frac{1}{C5^k}, |z| \le 1-\frac{1}{n_k}$. If we let $k \to \infty$ we get $\frac{1}{g}=0$ in the unit disc and that is a contradiction.

Note that $h(z)-w$ has the same properties as $h$ (taking all $k$ large enough so $5^k > 200|w|$ say, so we can use $C=\frac{1}{200}$ say, so the same proof applies to show that $h$ takes every complex value infinitely many times in the unit disc!

Comment: This is a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to the problem following the hint in **Rudin, W., *Real and Complex analysis*, McGrawHill, Third edition,**  for problem 6, chapter 13.

The key, as also pointed put in the OP and by others is to show that there is $c>0$ such that along any circle of radius $r_m:=1-\tfrac{1}{n_m}$
$$\begin{align}
|f(z)|\geq |5^mz^{n_m}|-|f(z) - 5^mz^{n_m}|\geq 5^m(r_m)^{n_m} -\sum_{\substack{k\geq1\\ k\neq m}}5^k(r_m)^{n_k}> 5^mc\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Zeroes of $f$**: Once this is proven, one can appeal to [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem). Let $p_m(z):=5^m z^{n_m}$. The polynomial $p_m$ has only one zero $z=0$ of multiplicity $n_m$ in $\mathcal{C}$. From \eqref{one},
$$
|f(z)-p_m(z)|<|p_m(z)|,\qquad |z|=r_m
$$
By Rouché's theorem $f$ has the same number of zeroes, $n_m$, as $g$ counted according to their multiplicities inside the disk $D(0;r_m)$. This implies that the number of zeroes of $f$ in $U$ us countably infinite ($r_m\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}1$ and $n_m>m$).

---

**Proof of \eqref{one}:** Here is a rather pedestrian approach. Notice that from
$n_1>1$ and $n_{k+1}>2k n_k$, it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
n_{k+m}> 2^k\Big((k-1+m)\cdot\ldots\cdot m \Big) n_m >2kmn_m \tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
$$
for all $k,\, m\geq1$. Along the circle  $|z|=r_m$
$$
\begin{align}
\Big|\sum^{m-1}_{k=1}5^kz^{n_k}\Big|\leq \sum^{m-1}_{k=1}5^k(r_m)^{n_k}\leq \frac{5^m}{4}\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
$$
Since $g(x)=\big(1-\tfrac{1}{x}\Big)^x$ is strictly monotone increasing in $[1,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}g(x)=e^{-1}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\Big|\sum^\infty_{k=m+1}5^kz^{n_k}\Big|&\leq 5^m\sum^\infty_{k=1}5^k(r_m)^{n_{k+m}}< 5^m\sum^\infty_{k=1} 5^k(r_m)^{2mkn_m}\\
&< 5^m\sum^\infty_{k=1} 5^k e^{-2mk}= 5^m\frac{5e^{-2m}}{1-5e^{-2m}}<5^m\frac{5e^{-6}}{1-5e^{-6}}\tag{4}\label{four}
\end{align}
$$
for $m\geq3$. Combining  \eqref{three} and \eqref{four} we obtain
$$
5^m(r_m)^{n_m}-\sum_{\substack{k\geq1\\ k\neq m}}5^k(r_m)^{n_k}>5^m\Big((r_m)^{n_m}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5e^{-6}}{1-5e^{-6}}\Big)\geq 5^m\Big((r_3)^{n_3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5e^{-6}}{1-5e^{-6}}\Big)
$$
for all $n\geq 3$. $n_3>8n_1>16$. A numeric calculation gives
$$
(r_3)^{n_3}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5e^{-6}}{1-5e^{-6}}>\big(1-\frac{1}{17}\big)^{17} -\frac14-\frac{5e^{-6}}{1-5e^{-6}}>0.09
$$
Inequality \eqref{one} follows from this.

---

**Final comments:**

- From \eqref{two} we habe that the the radius of convergcen of $f$ is $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{5^k}=1$. That $\limsup_{r\rightarrow1-}|f(re^{i\theta}|=\infty$ for all $\theta$ shows that $f$ cannot be extended analytically to any region containing $U$.
- As pointed out by others, one can also show that for any $w\in\mathbb{C}$, there are infinitely many solutions to the equation $f(z)=w$, $z\in U$. Indeed, along $|z|=r_m$
  $$|f(z)-w|\geq |p_m(z)|-|f(z)-w-p_m(z)|\geq |p_m(z)|-|f(z)-p_n(z)|-|w|> 5^mc-|w|>0
  $$
  for all sufficiently large $m$. Another application of Rouche's theorem shows that $f-w$ has $n_m$ solutions (counted according to their multiplicities) inside the disk $D(0;r_m)$ (for each $m$ large enough).

---